# Multi-select from bootstrap form - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a list of products and I want the user to be able to choose one or more from the list.

If I click/select a product for the first time, the `console.log` shows the right outcome.
However, if I click two times or more,  I get the error:

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I have tried two different strategies but both are failing (check the function `addSelectedProducts`):

**First solution**

```
function SearchProductForm() {
    const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = React.useState([]);

    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        }

    function addSelectedProducts(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setSelectedProducts(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
        console.log(selectedProducts)
    }

        return (
            <div>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
                        <Form.Label>Select the product(s) you are interested about:</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select" multiple onChange={(event) => addSelectedProducts(event)}>
                            <option value="product1">product1</option>
                            <option value="product2">product2</option>
                            <option value="product3">product3</option>
                            <option value="product4">product4</option>
                            <option value="product5">product5</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default SearchProductForm;
```

**Second solution**

```
function SearchProductForm() {
    const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = React.useState([]);

function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    }

function addSelectedProducts(event) {
    let options = event.target.options
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            setSelectedProducts(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
            console.log(selectedProducts)

        }
    }
}

    return (
        <div>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
                    <Form.Label>Select the product(s) you are interested about:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="select" onChange={(event) => addSelectedProducts(event)} multiple>
                        <option value="product1">product1</option>
                        <option value="product2">product2</option>
                        <option value="product3">product3</option>
                        <option value="product4">product4</option>
                        <option value="product5">product5</option>
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}>
                    Search
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just logging `event` to see what it looks like?

Comment: Yes, the first time I click on the list (if I click it the first time), it shows the right value. If I click a second time, it break giving me that error.

Comment: I've been trying to create a reproducible example on a code pen but I'm having trouble doing it. Would you happen to have a shareable example?

Comment: Also have you put a `debugger` instead of `console.log` for the `event`? This way it won't break and you can see what's getting passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ricardo touched on event pooling in their answer but I want to propose a solution where you don't need to persist the event, that's a bit code-smelly for me.

You can grab all the selected options at once and then set them instead of trying to merge new state with old state.

```
function addSelectedProducts(event) {
  // Alternative if you need to target ie
  // const selectedOptions = [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)

  const selectedOptions = [...event.target.selectedOptions].map(o => o.value)

  setSelectedProducts(selectedOptions)
}
```

The reason you're encountering the error above, is that

```
setSelectedProducts(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
```

is async and by the time the callback is invoked, your event is no longer around. See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-haibt-hp6mp

Comment: @rofrol I must have deleted it doing spring cleaning on my codesandbox. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you checked the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)? Maybe you have to add `event.persist()` cause you are handling the `event` inside a `function`.

```
 function addSelectedProducts(event) {
        event.persist()
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setSelectedProducts(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
        console.log(selectedProducts)
    }
```

Other solution can involve setting a variable to the `event.target.value`:

```
 function addSelectedProducts(event) {
        let value = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setSelectedProducts(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
        console.log(selectedProducts)
    }
```

Comment: This is not giving me the error, and the `setSelectedProducts` updates `selectedProducts`. However, it updates the array everytime I click. For example: if I click on product1, then click on product2 (thus de-selecting product1), both products are saved into `selectedProducts`

Answer (score 0):

I think  you can try `onChange={addSelectedProducts}` instead of `onChange={(event) => addSelectedProducts(event)}`